# How do i calculate the running time for a hybrid algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort, insertion-sort

I have a project to program a hybrid algorithm and calculate the running time for it.

I programed the hybrid algorithm, where i have insertion sort algorithm and merge sort algorithm, and after the user enters the unsorted array the program will call the most appropriate algorithm (which can either be insertion sort or merge sort) upon a threshold i specified, my question is how do I calculate the running time for this hybrid algorithm?

Because the way I see it the program can only apply one algorithm at each time, have this ever been done before? please tell me if you know a name for this so i can search it.

(p.s. what i have is the most basic form of insertion sort and merge sort “the merge sort is with exactly two halves” so they have typical time complexity)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's the worse complexity of the two algorithm.

Comment: @Max: The very simple algorithm "If input has size < 10: Use insertion sort. Else: Use merge sort." has worst-case time complexity of θ(N log N), which is not the worse of [θ(N^2), θ(N log N)].

Comment: Normally a hybrid insertion and merge sort use both insertion sort and merge sort, insertion sort for small runs and merge sort for larger runs. For example, Visual Studio's std::stable_sort(), uses insertion sort for runs <= 32 elements, and bottom up merge sort for runs > 32 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) does something very similar. If you carefully crafted your threshold, you are likely to end up with O(N log N) run time complexity, which is the best you can achieve for comparison-based sorting.

In theory, insertion sort has the better best-case complexity of O(N), so you might be able to reach that, too, for a best-case scenario. However, if your algorithm is a simple

```py
if input_size < threshold:
    insertion_sort(data)
else:
    merge_sort(data)
```

then you wouldn't achieve this, since for large inputs, you would always use merge-sort.

Usually, this whole thing is done to achieve a practical constant speed-up on a real computer by using algorithms that *very specific* computers can do faster in some cases. If we're just looking at this from a time complexity theory point of view, it wouldn't make much sense to switch from merge sort to insertion sort, except for the case that the input data is already (mostly) sorted. Also note that complexity theory does not consider absolute run times, but rather the relationship between run times and input size.

How much you actually increase the performance (and whether you increase it at all) is very hard to say, and depends on a lot of factors. Usually, you would want to properly benchmark your algorithm and simply measure how much faster it is.

Comment: You mean i should choose the highest complexity between my two algorithms? so i should go with the worst case for merge sort as the complexity for the hybrid algorithm?

Comment: In my project i'm actually asked to use some very very small numbers and some not very small (we're talking n=11 or 13 or 150 or even 5 or 9 just to test at what point insertion sort was faster than merge sort) and based off of my experiment i would make my threshold, so small numbers will call insertion sort function and big numbers call merge sort functions

Comment: No. Insertion sort has average and worst-case complexity of O(N^2), and as I explained, you probably get O(N log N) complexity, so you do not get the highest complexity between your two base algorithms.

You haven't really specified what your actual decision criterion is, so I can not give you an absolute answer. I have modified my answer a bit to be more clear -- if you simply set up a size-threshold and always use insertion sort below that threshold and merge sort above it, you will get O(N log N) complexity -- asymptotically, your algorithm would always be merge sort in this case.

Comment: About your project: So, semantically, you're always taking merge sort, except for a finite amount of input sizes, where you are using insertion sort right? This means, for any input size, you can exactly specify the run time as "it will take as long as insertion sort" or "it will take as long as merge sort". For the total time complexity: Keep in mind that we're talking about asymptotic behavior here. We want to know: "For big input sizes, if I change the input size, how will the run time change?". The few cases where you do not use merge sort have no impact on this.